# Is there a way to expand linked EPS file placed inside another EPS file in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

I've placed an EPS file (File A) inside another EPS file (File B) and now need to completely break this link so that the artwork of File A becomes 100% editable part of File B.

I've tried embedding it via Save As when saving FileB and that seems to keep the link to FileA active.

I do not want File A to be linked in any way and need the artwork of File A to be on same layer as the artwork of File B so that I can edit all artwork together.

I also do not want to have any links shown in the Illustrator links panel.

Please let me know how/if this can be accomplished?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Select the Linked File, click <kbd>Embed</kbd> on the toolbar at the top.

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

It should look like this when complete:

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

Comment: I am now trying to accomplish this with an action as I plan to work on multiple files. Is there a way to create an action or script to select and embed/expand external file(s) placed in an Illustrator file?