# Is there a way to create an action or script to select and embed external file(s) placed in an Illustrator file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

As a follow-up to my question [Is there a way to expand linked EPS file placed inside another EPS file in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28099/is-there-a-way-to-expand-linked-eps-file-placed-inside-another-eps-file-in-illus)

I am now trying to create an action to select and embed external file(s) placed in an Illustrator file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an action could be problematic, if at all possible. As for the script, Illustrator CS6 JS API exposes the *PlacedItem* object, which has the *embed* method.